# Fourier cosine transform of second derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

In lectures we defined the fourier and fourier cosine (for even functions) transforms as follows:
$$ \widehat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i \omega x} d x $$
$$ \widehat{f}_{c}(\omega)=\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \cos (\omega x)  d x $$

It is clear that $$ \widehat{f}(\omega) = 2 \widehat{f}_{c}(\omega) $$

Now we also derived two formulas for taking the fourier transforms and fourier cos transforms of second derivatives:
$$ \mathcal{F}\left\{d^{n} f / d x^{n}\right\}=(i \omega)^{n} \widehat{f}(\omega) $$
$$ \mathcal{F}_{c}\left\{f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right\}=-f^{\prime}(0)-\omega^{2} \widehat{f}_{c}(\omega) $$

But equating them with taking into account the factor of 2 leads to:

$$ \mathcal{F}_{c}\left\{f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right\} = -f^{\prime}(0)-\omega^{2} \widehat{f}_{c}(\omega) = \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{F}\left\{f^{\prime \prime}(x)\right\} = -\omega^{2} \widehat{f}_{c}(\omega) $$

Which suggest that $f^{\prime}(0) = 0$, which is not necessarily true, am I assuming something incorrect here?

Comment: $f'(0)$ of a differentiable even function $f$ is?

Comment: ah right, yeah, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an even function $f$, i.e. $f(-x) = f(x)$,

$$\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= \frac{df(x)}{dx}\\
&= \frac{df(-x)}{dx}\\
&= \frac{df(-x)}{d(-x)}\frac{d(-x)}{dx}\\
&=  -f'(-x)
\end{align*}$$

This shows $f'$ is odd, and by substituting $x=0$,
$$f'(0) = 0$$